# Need to display multiple renderings in a Tab view

Tags: presentation

I am using Sitecore 9 and I need to display 5 controller renderings in a Tabbed view.

I looked at the article:
[How to show three different Tabs rendering by using Sitecore in ASP.NET MVC](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6340/how-to-show-three-different-tabs-rendering-by-using-sitecore-in-asp-net-mvc)

But could not create the desired result. Can you please share more detailed steps or a sample with two renderings/items displayed as two tabs.

Thanks
Om

Comment: Would like to update that the way I was doing , it worked, the problem was not with rendering but datasource was null , thats why it was not showing anything. thanks
OM

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it with dynamic placeholders. 
For example, your need following markup:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">Controller Rendering 1 Content</div>
    <div class="tab">Controller Rendering 2 Content</div>
    <div class="tab">Controller Rendering 3 Content</div>
    <div class="tab">Controller Rendering 4 Content</div>
    <div class="tab">Controller Rendering 5 Content</div>
</div>
```

You need to have one rendering that is your tabs wrapper (container):

```
<div class="tabs">
    @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder(new DynamicPlaceholderDefinition("tab-item")
    {
        OutputModifier = (input, context) => new HtmlString("<div class="tab">" + input + "</div>")
    })
</div>
```

And you need your 5 controller renderings, that are assigned to "tab-item" placeholder.
Open experience editor and insert your renderings in container in needed sequence.

Try to use html markup where tab menu links are inside tabs content. Something like this https://kyusuf.com/post/completely-css-tabs

Comment: okay let me explain in detail:

Comment: I have default.html as layout , it has @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("content"). When Login and Account controller renderings are added are using 'content' as placeholder, page is working. Now to convert it to Tabs , I added a view rendering , assigned  'content' as placeholder, and added following markup:  <div class="tab-content">
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("LoginTab")
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("AccountTab")</div> I expected both to be displayed as two tabs, but nothing is being displayed. Not sure what I am missing.